# variable for font size in tumblr themes

Tags: tumblr, tumblr-themes

How can I add a variable that change the font sizes in a tumblr theme?

**HTML**

```
<meta name="size:Whateveriwant" content:"">
```

**CSS**

```
font-size: {size:Whateveriwant};
```

I know you can use option types such as color, text, image, boolean, but can you make your own, such as size?

Comment: Welcome to SO! Maybe look at the documentation  https://www.tumblr.com/docs/en/custom_themes#theme-options - tl;dr You can't make a custom option! :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, you can't create a custom theme option, such as size.

However, it is possible to do something similar. Use the text theme option, which acts like a string.

**HTML**

```
<meta name="text:Whateveriwant" content:"16px">
```

**CSS**

```
font-size: {text:Whateveriwant};
```

**Rendered CSS**

```
font-size: 16px;
```